# export PDF from report directly

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I use Oracle Report 6 for get my report, The problem is I want to get PDF export without displaying the report.I mean right now, I click on one button and make report (call a report from my Oracle form) then go to my report menu ->Generate to File -> PDF.

I dont want do this anymore... can I use any command from my form to export my report directly? I mean for example use some command to prepare report and get export in PDF automatically...

also if I can set the export file name and it's location when I try to generate PDF also can help me so much because I need to follow some rule for put name for my export files like use prefix and some digit and number....

What is your suggestion?

Comment: nobody can not answer my question or it is not clear???

Answer (score 1):

You can do both request.

You have to create parameter and pass to run_product built-in

Syntax:

```
REPORT_DESTYPE: File, Printer, Mail, Cache   -- SET File
REPORT_FILENAME: The report filename (not used with CACHE)  -- Set your desirable file name format
REPORT_DESNAME: The report destination name (not used with Cache) -- 
REPORT_DESFORMAT: The report destination format  -- <HTML|HTMLCSS|PDF|RTF|XML|DELIMITED> set PDF
```

Sample parameter list:
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(v_report_id,REPORT_DESFORMAT, 
'');

I hope this help.

If you still need full details let me know, i'll add a sample procedure.

Comment: Hi hi,actually I would so appreciate if u provide me a sample procedure. I want surprise my college. It waste so much time from us...

Comment: I think this text just help us to set the name of export file,am I right? u said: "You can do both request". Would u please tell me how can I get PDF export directly,I didn't get u clearly...

Comment: do u think this one is correct I find it from google   http://www.cnet411.com/tnt/ans.asp?cat=Oracle&ID=161&hd=db

Answer (score 0):

Use these parameter fields:

```
ADD_PARAMETER(p1,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'FILE');
ADD_PARAMETER(p1,'DESFORMAT',TEXT_PARAMETER,'PDF');
ADD_PARAMETER(p1,'DESNAME',TEXT_PARAMETER,'C:\Downloads\MRP_PROCESSRATE.PDF');
```